# Replacing DC power adapter - choose fixed or variable?

Tags: power-supply

I have an older network device powered by an AC/DC power adapter rated to have 5 V/2 A DC output.  The device itself stopped working, so I tested the adapter with a digital multimeter & found its output to be only 4.2 V (which I suspect means that power adapter is wearing out).

But what I don't know is whether that much undervoltage is enough to have damaged the network device so I can't expect it will work at all again, OR if it will work fine again if I just replace the power adapter with a new one so it again gets the full 5 V/2 A it's spec'd for.  Because such power adapters are relatively cheap, I'm going to buy one & try it with the network device to find out.

However, I've found that I can buy such a power adapter with a fixed 5 V/2 A output ... OR (& for very little more) I can buy a model (36 W) that has a dial to vary the DC output voltage between 3 V & 12 V at several specified steps (including 5 V) & supply from 0.5 A up to 2.5 A.

If my network device is already "shot", then having that variable adapter would increase the chance I might be able to use it with some other device in the future.

But what I don't know (& would appreciate advice on) is whether there are any negative trade-offs in using such a "variable" power adapter that I should consider first, particularly if any might mean it would be advisable that I buy the fixed voltage model instead.

---

Thanks very much!  All good thoughts!

About the 4.2 V, though, I wasn't thinking that just hitting 4.2 V would harm the device, I really was concerned about possible damage over time due to the device being forced to run at a lower voltage than it was designed for.  I'm not an engineer, but I can imagine two design concepts:
(1) If it doesn't detect the availability of (say) +/- 5% of 5 V, then it won't either start up or run (protective); or

(2) It can both start & run (though inefficiently) at a lower voltage, but that power “brownout” forces the device's circuitry to "work so hard" trying to get sufficient "juice" from just that 4.2 V power supply that, over time, the circuitry in the device is damaged such that the device no longer can function at all, even after a new “in spec” power adapter is attached to it.
In the case of this device, it was originally plugged into a wall outlet maybe 8-10 years ago & the device kept running . . . until it didn’t.  So if the power adapter originally output the correct 5 VDC power but, over time, wore out so it was only putting out that 4.2 VDC power, with either of those designs, the device would have stopped working.  If it was (1), then with a new properly spec'd power adapter, it should start running again.  If the design was like (2), getting that new power adapter won’t “revive” it & I might as well just throw away the device as non-functional.

Comment: It could also increase you frying a device by having the wrong voltage set.

Answer (score 2):

5 V logic devices often have a narrow voltage tolerance. If under-volted they won't work and if overvolted they can be destroyed. For this reason most would include a 5 V regulator inside the device and feed the device with a few volts more than that - typically 9 V. Yours is odd in that it requires a 5 V supply.

Many of the adjustable voltage PSUs (power supply units) are not regulated. The output voltage will be high when unloaded and will droop when a load is attached. I don't think it's worth the risk.

5 V, 2 A is commonly available on generic USB phone and table power supplies, they are widely available and very cheap due to their popularity. I recommend that you buy one of these with USB power lead, cut the micro USB connector off and attach the red and black wires to the old plug observing polarity carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather just have the 5 V supply. My assumption is that it will be of higher quality than one which has selectable voltages, and will be less cumbersome and more foolproof. Kind of a flimsy rationale, but that is my thinking on it. The only real downside to a selectable voltage model is that you might accidentally apply the wrong voltage to something at some point thus causing it to fail.

Very unlikely that a 5 V device would be damaged by the application of 4.2 V. The reason is that it ramps up through 4.2 V every time you apply power. If 4.2 V could damage it, it would be damaged right away every time you power it up.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Good thoughts!  About the 4.2v, I wasn't thinking that just hitting 4.2v might harm the device, it was more of a concern about possible damage  the device might suffer over a period of time running at lower voltage than it was designed for.  I'm not an engineer at all, but I can imagine two ways to design such a product:.

Comment: I see your point about low voltage. I guess my opinion is that damage from low voltage is very unlikely. I didn't mean to imply that it was a dumb question or anything like that.

Comment: Sure.  I didn't take it that way at all.  Your thoughts were helpful.